# font-size increases unexpectedly in mobile webkit

Tags: android, ios, css, webkit, mobile-webkit

I'm working on optimizing a website for mobile devices, and I'm nearly done (yay!) but one thing makes me rack my brain:

**How it works**

I used CSS to restyle a tab-bar (actually a list) to work like a dropdown-menu. When touching the only visible list element, jQuery toggles the class "open" on the `ul`-element and all list elements appear also. That's how it works.

**The Problem**

When unfolding the dropdown-menu, it's font-size increases from 15px to 19px. And in Inspector there is absolutely no hint why this happens. Adding a rule like `font-size: 15px !important;` has no effect.

I made a little screencast for you: http://youtu.be/MUTJfTK70PE?hd=1

**Affected devices**

1. Android (Samsung Galaxy)
2. iOS (iPod, iPhone, Simulator)

Windows Phone (Internet Explorer) is **not affected** (wow!)

I would be very thankful for every single idea!!

Comment: Also a funny point: the font size does only increase in landscape view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that Mobile Webkits font resizing was the origin.
This rule solved it:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding something like this: `font-size: 1.5rem;`

Comment: It does not have any effect, it only reduces the height of the list-element :(

Comment: One last try. User em instead of rem. I am using a similar nav and works :/

Comment: Also no luck. Do you use it also on a mobile page? On desktop browsers the nav is working fine.

Comment: Yeah I am using both BlackBerry and iOS and it works fine hmm

Answer (score 0):

In html5 this is best solved by explicitly setting the viewport in the page header. The statement

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

turns mobile font resizing off. Setting text-size-adjust to none has the disadvantage of disabling zoom on mobile devices, still requires heavy prefixing and the value none seems to be ignored by some browsers.